# How do you join two many to many tables in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a few Tables I want to join together:

- Users
- UserRoles
- WorkflowRoles
- Role
- Workflow

The equivalent sql I want to generate is something like

```
select * from Users u
inner join UserRoles ur on u.UserId = ur.UserId
inner join WorkflowRoles wr on wr.RoleId = ur.RoleId
inner join Workflow w on wr.WorkflowId = w.Id
where u.Id = x
```

I want to get all the workflows a user is part of based on their roles in one query.  I've found that you can get the results like this:

```
user.Roles.SelectMany(r => r.Workflows)
```

but this generates a query for each role which is obviously less than ideal.

Is there a proper way to do this without having to resort to hacks like generating a view or writing straight sql?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try the following two queries:

This one is better readable, I think:

```
var workflows = context.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserId == givenUserId)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Roles.SelectMany(r => r.Workflows))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

(`Distinct` because a user could have two roles and these roles may contain the same workflow. Without `Distinct` duplicate workflows would be returned.)

But this one performs better, I believe:

```
var workflows = context.WorkFlows
    .Where(w => w.Roles.Any(r => r.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == givenUserId)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the order which you select makes the difference:

```
user.Select(x => x.Roles.SelectMany(y => y.Workflows)).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have not had a chance to test this, but it should work:

```
Users.Include(user => user.UserRoles).Include(user => user.UserRole.WorkflowRoles.Workflow)
```

If the above is not correct then is it possible that you post your class structure?